# Automate a task with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, backup, scheduled-tasks

I have this code to automate the backup of folders and it does the job well. I however want to up the notch on it by making it do the backing up automatically by 12PM everyday. Ant hints on how to go about this would be seriously appreciated.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dstr As String
    Dim mstr As String
    Dim ystr As String
    Dim folstr As String
    Dim dsumstr As String

    dstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd")
    mstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM")
    ystr = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy")
    dsumstr = ystr & "-" & mstr & "-" & dstr
    folstr = "Y:\server1\Fileserver-" & dsumstr
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr)

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr & "\SHARE-AC")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("D:\SHARE-AC", folstr & "\SHARE-AC")



        Label1.Text = "Back up DATE   " & dsumstr & "  Complete"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = (ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

For our Windows Servers we use the Task Scheduler. You can read more [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer - as follows:

```
Dim WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
```

Set up your variables (or read them from wherever).

```
Dim runtimestring As String = "12:00 PM"
Dim nextruntime As Date
```

On start up set the interval to the next runtime and start the timer:

```
Sub New()
    'set up time interval
    If Now.TimeOfDay > Date.Parse(runtimestring).TimeOfDay Then
        'set nextruntime to tomorrow
        nextruntime = Date.Parse(runtimestring).AddDays(1)
    Else
        'set nextruntime to today
        nextruntime = Date.Parse(runtimestring)
    End If
    Timer1.Interval = nextruntime.Subtract(Now).TotalMilliseconds
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

In the Tick event, stop the timer carry out your functions/subs as required and then re-set the interval and start the timer again.

```
Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    'Add your functions and sub's here.....


    'set nextruntime to tomorrow
    nextruntime = Date.Parse(runtimestring).AddDays(1)
    Timer1.Interval = nextruntime.Subtract(Now).TotalMilliseconds
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment? - if you leave a comment I hopefully can improve the answer!